# Using df.withColumn() on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spss-modeler

I am working with python and pyspark to extend the SPSS Modeler.

I want to manipulate ~5000 columns and therefore use the following construct:

```
for target in targets:
    inputData = inputData.withColumn(target+appendString, function(target))
```

This is very slow. Is there a more efficent way to do this for all target columns?

`targets` contains a list of column names to be used, `function(target)` is a placeholder where I do stuff with different columns like adding and dividing.

I would be happy if you could help me :)

pandayo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
inputData.select(
    '*', 
    *(function(target).alias(target+appendString) for target in targets)
)
```

Comment: Can you compare the execution plan of this method vs. the one proposed by OP? I suspect that, while this looks neater, it's actually doing the same thing under the hood.

Comment: This method does not re-affect the dataframe each time. you generate only one dataframe. But yeah, the execution plan is probably the same otherwise

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.